# Moving a Column into JSONB Field as Key

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I'm using Postgres database and have a table like below

```
id    firstname    lastname  settings
 1     Sam          Crews    {"some_key": some_value}
 2     John         Dave     {"some_key": some_value}
```

I am trying to move one of the columns into settings json and drop the column. So it becomes,

```
id    firstname      settings
 1     Sam           {"some_key": some_value, "lastname": "Crews"}
 2     John          {"some_key": some_value, "lastname": "Dave"}
```

What is the postgres syntax for moving column to in jsonb field? Been searching but can not seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run an update to add the key/value pair to the existing JSON value.

```
update the_table 
   set settings = settings||jsonb_build_object('lastname', lastname)
```

if it's possible that `settings` is null, you can e.g. use `coalesce()`

```
update the_table 
   set settings = coalesce(settings, '{}) || jsonb_build_object('lastname', lastname)
```

then you can drop the column

```
alter table the_table
  drop column lastname;
```

But this sounds like a bad idea. Why de-normalize this and make your life harder in the long run?

Comment: actual column is part of setting rest of the settings is kept as jsonb field that is the column i am trying to move.